# Consequenses of changing UPN and migrating 'cloud only' to 'hybrid' users

Tags: active-directory, cloud, entra-id, entra-domain-services, upn

We are going to change the domain name in our company, and by doing so, change all of the current users UPN from xxx@oldDomain.com to xxx@newDomain.com and add the old email as an "alias".

And at the same time, these all users will be migrated from cloud only, to hybrid (on-premise, synced to cloud).

What is this going to effect?

The setup on user pc's is local user accounts(non ad connected), but work/school account added in "email & accounts", and is used for outlook.

Looking for similar experiences/how to prepare the best.

Initial thoughts were:

Will the outlook profile break, and new one needs to be created?
Will the connected account, with the old UPN, continue to work, based on SID and not UPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook profiles won't break.

You'll typically just need to sign out and sign back into the Office apps with the new UPN on each end user computer/device.

OneDrive will detect the change and will update itself, though you should be aware of how a UPN change affects OneDrive. Read the linked article below.

You'll need to close and reopen your OneNote notebooks if you use OneNote. Read the linked article below.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/upn-changes